# Python default version errors

Tags: debian, python

For a while I've been getting this error while doing anything `apt-get` related:

```
Preparing to replace python-cairo 1.4.12-1.2 (using .../python-cairo_1.8.8-1+b1_i386.deb) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
  File "/usr/share/pycentral-data/pyversions.py", line 172, in default_version
    raise ValueError, "/usr/bin/python does not match the python default version. It must be reset to point to %s" % debian_default
ValueError: /usr/bin/python does not match the python default version. It must be reset to point to python2.6.6
```

Whereas

```
robus:/# /usr/bin/python -V
Python 2.6.6
```

How do I fix this? I did try fixing symlinks, but then I keep getting 'too many symlink levels' errors.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit surprised that it requires `python2.6.6` and not `python2.6` (for packaging purposes only two-part version numbers are usually used). This seems to come from `/usr/share/python/debian_defaults`, which on my system contains `default-version = python2.7`. What does the `default-version` line in your file contain, and has this file been changed at all on your system?

Comment: `default-version = python2.6`, used to be 2.6.6 I believe